# Win API to determine if webcam is in use by other apps

Tags: c#, winapi, webcam

In Skype, if the webcam is in use, it shows a relevant message. Is this possible using Win API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know absolutely nothing about the imaging API, but I suppose that you may simply try to open the webcam and check the error code: probably there's an error code that means "device already open". If you get that code you can display a relevant error message.

Comment: Well, it's indeed funny to get your answer accepted after ~9 months. :)